# Should the [helix] tag be split, or removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [helix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helix) may refer to

- [Helix Toolkit](https://github.com/helix-toolkit) as a toolkit for use of DirectX and PresentationCore with WPF in C#
- [Apache Helix](https://helix.apache.org/), as a toolkit for networked cluster management
- [the Helix geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281577/helix-central-axis-angle) well known for its role in DNA visualisations

When opening the [search list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helix) for this tag, things are mixed up.

---

At first, I missed the specific tag, but searching for them, I find below tags ! Things are getting mixed up, because the single [helix] tag is used for all topics:

[image]

Comment: My 2 cents: don't keep the tag for the geometric figure.  It doesn't really add anything and leaves it around for misuse.  I generally agree with your other proposals as well.

Comment: Yes that may be the issue. Disambiguation. I've found all three AND the single [helix] tag, which is used  in most cases.

Comment: Looks like the tags have been split since 2013: [helix-3d-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15597597/revisions), [helix-server](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/241328/revisions), [helix-dna-server](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/580392/revisions), though 'helix' was still used for many other meanings.

Comment: Yes, that is why I put the note and changed the title. Initially, I assumed these extra tags did not exist. I have put a 3th edit to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure that ["Helix geometry" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281577/helix-central-axis-angle) should even be open; it's tagged "matlab" but isn't programming focused at all, it's just asking about the math itself.